# Determine value of columns on each row based on date offsets and column condition, and thus inputting values from corresponding offseted rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, apply

I want to add a series of columns whose value is determined from date offsets present from a selection of boolean columns (in this case y0, y1, y2,y3) from the current year.

Consider the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Raw Data
years = ["2000", "2001", "2002", "2003"]
num_combos = len(years)
products = ["A"] * num_combos
bools = [True, False, True, False]
bools1 = [False, True, False, np.nan]
bools2 = [True, False, np.nan, np.nan]
bools3 = [False, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
values = [100, 97, 80, np.nan]

cols = {"years": years,
        "products": products,
        "y0": bools,
        "y1": bools1,
        "y2": bools2, 
        "y3": bools3,
        "value": values}
df = pd.DataFrame(cols)
df[["y0", "y1", "y2", "y3"]] = df[["y0", "y1", "y2", "y3"]].astype(float)
```

Consider the year 2000

y0 is 1 so the value at year 2000 (value_0) is 100
y1 is 0 so the value at year 2000 one year into the future (value_1) is NaN
y2 is 1 so the value at year 2000 two years into the future (value_2) is the value at 2002 which is 80 etc

This would yield the following dataframe.

```
df["value_0"] = [100, np.nan, 80, np.nan]
df["value_1"] = [np.nan, 80, np.nan, np.nan]
df["value_2"] = [80, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
df["value_3"] = [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
```

Is there a clever way of determining these columns using apply or np.where? (or alternative)

Answer (score 0):

With the dataframe `df` you provided, here is one way to do it using Pandas [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html), [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), and [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```py
# Setup
counter = range(df.shape[0])

# Add new columns and rows
temp_df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[df["value"].shift(-i).T for i in counter],
)
temp_df.columns = [f"value_{i}" for i in counter]
temp_df.index = [i for i in counter]
df = pd.concat([df, temp_df], axis=1)

# Update values according to "y0", "y1", ... columns
for i in counter:
    df[f"value_{i}"] = df.apply(
        lambda x: x[f"value_{i}"] if x[f"y{i}"] else None, axis=1
    )
```

```py
print(df)
# Output
  years products   y0   y1   y2   y3  value  value_0  value_1  value_2  \
0  2000        A  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  100.0    100.0      NaN     80.0   
1  2001        A  0.0  1.0  0.0  NaN   97.0      NaN     80.0      NaN   
2  2002        A  1.0  0.0  NaN  NaN   80.0     80.0      NaN      NaN   
3  2003        A  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   

   value_3  
0      NaN  
1      NaN  
2      NaN  
3      NaN
```